# How to remove Query String "?" (question mark) from URL (Using Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, query-string

I was using wordpress 3.3 to power my website. I tested it with Page Speed and it gave me error "remove query string from URL).... The query string is a question mark which appears in the start of query paramter of the url.....

http://gizmocube.com/images/logo.png .... is outputted as ...

http://gizmocube.com/images/logo.png?9d7bd4

how do i get rid of this question mark.... any .htacess stuff... any help would be appreciated....

Comment: You should probably find out why that string is added in the first place. I don't think WP does that natively. Do you have some plugin  installed that is designed to prevent image caching?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have  W3 Total Cache Installed ? (Wordpress Plugin) , If you do

Go to the Browser Cache Tab

Untick

> **Prevent caching of objects after settings change**

Whenever settings are changed, a new query string will be generated and appended to objects allowing the new policy to be applied.

Clear the Cache then It's gone :)
Hope this helps

--
**Source**
Myself (Having the same issue myself )

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Browser Cache Tab > untick "Prevent caching of objects after settings change".

This will slove the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Permalink settings from the default with question marks to a format you prefer under `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`

- Default: http://www.example.com/?p=123
- Day and name: http://www.example.com/2012/03/02/sample-post/
- Month and name: http://www.example.com/2012/03/sample-post/
- Numeric: http://www.example.com/archives/123
- Post name: http://www.example.com/sample-post/
- Custom Structure: /%year%/%monthnum%/%postname%/

Comment: I don't see how this has to do with WP adding random stuff to *image* URLs?

Comment: Naah!! i know permalinks... they are completely fine... but A "?" MARK gets appended in front of many images, css and js.. i am using W3 Total cache ... could that cause the problem???

Comment: @ayoosh I saw some info on thumbnail images. Are these images smaller versions of the originals?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your functions.php file, it works for my sites.

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
$parts = explode( '?ver', $src );
    return $parts[0];
}
 add_filter('script_loader_src','_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter('style_loader_src','_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```